# Is there a way to grant access to a ServiceAccount from all namespaces in Kubernetes? Or a cluster-wide ServiceAccount?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, k8s-serviceaccount

I'm going to have an unknown number of users access my K8s (specifically OpenShift if that helps) cluster.  Each user will have their own random namespace.  So I do not know the namespaces in advance as they will be dynamically created. But I want each user to be able to utilize a ServiceAccount that I create ahead of time.

So, if I create a ServiceAccount `fooSA` in my namespace `foo`, I'd like to be able to define a deployment that utilizes `fooSA` from the `bar` namespace.  For example:

myapp.yaml

```
...
spec:
  serviceAccount: fooSA
...
```

`kubectl apply -f myapp.yaml -n bar`

How can I accomplish this?

As ServiceAccounts are namespace scoped I cannot figure out a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Much like credentials in other use cases, you shouldn't be sharing them between your workloads. Use [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) instead.

Comment: @elatedgoat Could you please share the status of your issue; If you have resolved your issue please post it so, that other community members can see it.